# How to refresh the current route without refreshing the parent(application) route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-model

i have a home route and when i refresh the page on the browser instead of calling the model and only refreshing the current route, it refreshes the parent(application) route. Is there any way to just refresh my home route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to do this. From within the application you can probably do it, but when the browser refreshes the page it's going to do a full refresh every time, no way around that.